# Link vb.net /android project with online database

Tags: android, mysql, .net, sql-server

I have a project in vb.net and another in android studio I want to link them with one database (real time connection) what is the best way to do that (sql server-my sql ....other?)

Answer (score 0):

Sql server is pretty easy to link to vb.net. you simply create a connection string with the server name and password, although I am not sure about android, but the process would probably be similar

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to communicate between the two applications via SQL server, is that correct? While it is possible to do this it is highly ill-advised as the communication cannot be realtime (you would have to poll a table by selecting from it every ## seconds or use triggers [MSSQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) / [MySQL](https://www.siteground.com/kb/mysql-triggers-use/) in a very strange way) and it is likely to be unnecessary.

My suggestion is to consider what data you need to go back and forth and why. It is unusual for an Android app to directly connect to a database across the Internet because of the [security risks](https://serverfault.com/questions/19945/the-wisdom-of-exposing-a-database-server-on-the-internet) in exposing a database publicly. Most developers opt to use a web application of some kind that provides an API for the Android app to consume. This prevents direct access to the database and provides you a place to add in all your business/game/other logic.